# python 3 convert list to csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv, python-3.6

I have below code

```
import requests, json

r = requests.get('http://someurl.com/api')
data = r.json()
flights = []
for flight in data:
    # print(flight['identifier'])
    if flight['STDudt'].strip() < flight['ETDudt'].strip() and flight['OUTudt'].strip() == '':
        flights.append(flight)

print(flights)
```

How can I convert it to csv file with keys of object as column names?

output i get from code looks like this:

```
[{'numGMTDate': '20180515', 'STDudt': '1405', 'STAudt': '1545', 'ETDudt': '1415', 'OUTudt': '', 'OFFudt': ''},{'numGMTDate': '20180515', 'STDudt': '1530', 'STAudt': '1831', 'ETDudt': '1540', 'OUTudt': '', 'OFFudt': ''}]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python convert JSON to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454216/python-convert-json-to-csv)

Comment: Also possible duplicate of [How do I convert this list of dictionaries to a csv file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3086973/how-do-i-convert-this-list-of-dictionaries-to-a-csv-file)

Answer (score 0):

One way that I know to go about this problem requires a bit of work,
first save the python code to a place where you can easily set up a file.
Now I am pretty lengthy with this and there are probably other ways but.

```
outfile = open ("STRING NAME.csv","w")
```

Will create the CSV file by "String Name" the .csv will make the file easier to open

```
outfile.write(value)
outfile.write(",")
```

will separate everything by commas
and at the end of each line that you want to write

```
outfile.write("\n")
```

will make a new line for the csv

```
outfile.close()
```

to finish it off

hope this helps

example of where I have used before

```
        while h<=math.sqrt(float(d)):
        if float(d/(h*h))!=float(int(d/(h*h))):
            h=h+1
        else:
            j=h
            h=h+1
    if j==int(1) or int(d/(j*j))==1:
        a=a
    else:
        if j/2==int(j/2):
            a=a
        else:     
            outfile.write(str(int(b)))
            outfile.write(",")
            outfile.write(str(int(c)))
            outfile.write(",")
            outfile.write(str(int(d)))
            outfile.write(",")
            outfile.write(str(int(g)))
            outfile.write(",")
            outfile.write(str(int(j)))
            outfile.write(",")
            outfile.write(str(int(d/(j*j))))
            outfile.write(",")
            print("b=",int(b)," and c=",c)
            print(float(d)," has a square root of ",float(j)," rad ",float(d/(j*j)))
        a=a+1
    if a==16:
        z=input("SO....")
        if z==str("good"):
            a=16
        else:
            a=1
            print("Fui")
            outfile.write("Bad")
            outfile.write("\n")
    while a==16 and p<10:
        outfile.write("\n")
        p=p+1
        print("new line")
        a=1
outfile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm almost there based on code found on suggested duplicate. Only problem is it leaves a blank row between each row.

```
import requests, json

    r = requests.get('http://someurl.com/api')
    data = r.json()
    flights = []
    for flight in data:
        # print(flight['identifier'])
        if flight['STDudt'].strip() < flight['ETDudt'].strip() and flight['OUTudt'].strip() == '':
            flights.append(flight)

    keys = flights[0].keys()
    with open('filteredData.csv', 'w') as output_file:
        dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(output_file, keys)
        dict_writer.writeheader()
        dict_writer.writerows(flights)
```

[image]