# How to show specific page views using Google Analytics API?

Tags: python, dataframe, csv, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

for an API that I am using, we need to be able to view what specific pages are being clicked on and output to a CSV File. I am  able to see the average session duration, and the amount of page views. I am curious as to what I need to add into my code attached below to make sure that this is possible for exporting to a CSV file. Thank you!

```
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly']
KEY_FILE_LOCATION = 'client_secrets.json'
VIEW_ID ='insert here'

credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name(KEY_FILE_LOCATION, SCOPES)

# Build the service object.
analytics = build('analyticsreporting', 'v4', credentials=credentials)

response = analytics.reports().batchGet(body={
'reportRequests': [{
    'viewId': VIEW_ID,
    'dateRanges': [{'startDate': '30daysAgo', 'endDate': 'today'}],
     'metrics': [
         {"expression": "ga:pageviews"},
         {"expression": "ga:avgSessionDuration"}
      ], "dimensions": [
          {"name": "ga:deviceCategory"}
      ]
   }]}).execute()
```

response

> {'reports': [{'columnHeader': {'dimensions': ['ga:deviceCategory'],
> 'metricHeader': {'metricHeaderEntries': [{'name': 'ga:pageviews',
> 'type': 'INTEGER'},
> {'name': 'ga:avgSessionDuration', 'type': 'TIME'}]}},
> 'data': {'isDataGolden': True,
> 'maximums': [{'values': ['485', '94.95454545454545']}],
> 'minimums': [{'values': ['29', '51.21186440677966']}],
> 'rowCount': 3,
> 'rows': [{'dimensions': ['desktop'],
> 'metrics': [{'values': ['485', '51.21186440677966']}]},
> {'dimensions': ['mobile'],
> 'metrics': [{'values': ['409', '69.30859375']}]},
> {'dimensions': ['tablet'],
> 'metrics': [{'values': ['29', '94.95454545454545']}]}],
> 'totals': [{'values': ['923', '60.06487341772152']}]}}]}

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Name', 'Age'])


def ga_response_dataframe(response):
  row_list = []
  # Get each collected report
  for report in response.get('reports', []):
      # Set column headers
      column_header = report.get('columnHeader', {})
      dimension_headers = column_header.get('dimensions', [])
      metric_headers = column_header.get('metricHeader', {}).get('metricHeaderEntries', [])

      # Get each row in the report
      for row in report.get('data', {}).get('rows', []):
          # create dict for each row
          row_dict = {}
          dimensions = row.get('dimensions', [])
          date_range_values = row.get('metrics', [])

      # Fill dict with dimension header (key) and dimension value (value)
          for header, dimension in zip(dimension_headers, dimensions):
              row_dict[header] = dimension

      # Fill dict with metric header (key) and metric value (value)
          for i, values in enumerate(date_range_values):
              for metric, value in zip(metric_headers, values.get('values')):
                  # Set int as int, float a float
                  if ',' in value or '.' in value:
                      row_dict[metric.get('name')] = float(value)
                  else:
                      row_dict[metric.get('name')] = int(value)

          row_list.append(row_dict)
      df = row_list

  return df


 df = ga_response_dataframe(response)
#df = pd.DataFrame(row_list)
 print(df)
```

Comment: The api returns data in Json format, if you want to store it as a CSV then your going to have to parse it to that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python convert JSON to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30454216/python-convert-json-to-csv)